# A script isn't showing in the Content Browser

Tags: c++, unreal-4

Just to set the tone, I'm very new to game development.

I'm currently taking an online video course for Unreal Engine 4 that required me to create a C++ script. After I created the script and it compiled it did not appear in the Content Browser where it should be. I received the following text boxes:

[image: "Message dialog: Successfully added class 'ShipController', however you must recompile the 'SpaceShooter' module before it will appear in the Content Browser. Failed to generate project files. Would you like to open the Output Log to see more details? (Yes / No)]

and

[image]

Comment: Does the ShipController class have a UCLASS() declared above the class declaration? Do you have any source to show?

Answer (score 2):

With the information you've provided, my first thought would be to try the following:

- Compile your project in Unreal
- Clean and Compile your project in Visual Studio

Compiling your project in Unreal if you haven't already done it is straight forward, just press the Compile button in the toolbar above the Viewport.

To open your project inside Visual Studio, you can just right click on the Content folder inside the Content Browser, and select 'show in explorer' which will take you straight to the Content folder of your project inside file explorer. Navigate up one directory to go back to the main folder of your project. Assuming you are using Visual Studio with your project there should be a Microsoft Visual Studio Solution file located towards the bottom of this directory, named after the name of your project- 'SpaceShooter.sln' in your case. If you double click on this file, Visual Studio will open your solution, containing all of your C++ files.

To clean your project, select Edit, then Clean from the menu at the top of Visual Studio. Then select Edit and Build, or just press Ctr + Shift + Build to compile your project. Now go back and compile your project again inside Unreal using the tool bar. Hopefully your files should show inside the content browser at this point.

It's also worth noting that your C++ files aren't shown directly in the Content folder of the Content Browser, just on the off chance that you're looking in the wrong place after trying the steps above. To show your C++ classes in the Content Browser, you need to press the 'show or hide sources panel' indicated by an arrow pointing to the left on the side of the content browser, and then select the C++ Classes folder.

These might seem like fairly trivial suggestions, but hopefully it's a trivial problem to begin with. Without more information it's hard to know where else to go from there though. Try to give as much info as you can when asking questions as it makes it easier to give you a targeted answer- the output log is a good start, but it would be more useful to know specifically what you did leading up to the issue you're experiencing, in addition to anything you tried after experiencing the issue to try and remedy it. What steps did you take to create the script for example? Did you attempt the above suggestions already? What version of Unreal Engine are you using?

Not having a go at you by any means, just a tip to help you ask better questions so that you can get better answers in the future.